# Performing a lookup in JavaScript and printing the result in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have this "summary builder" on my site and everything is working great except the lookup part. 
HTML:

```
<tr>
<td>Building ID:</td>
<td> 
<table>
<tr> <td>
<form action="Building">
Building:<input type="text" size=3 maxlength=3 id="txt3"  onkeyup="showHint(this.value.toUpperCase(),'txtBuilding')">
</form> </td>
<td>
<form action="">
Floor:<input type="text" size=2 maxlength=2 id="txt3" onkeyup="showHint(this.value.toUpperCase(),'txtFloor')">
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form action="">
Room:<input type="text" size=4 maxlength=4 id="txt3"  onkeyup="showHint(this.value.toUpperCase(),'txtRoom')" >
</form> </td> 
</tr> </table> 
</td> </tr>
<p><span id="txtBuilding"></span>
<span id="txtFloor"></span>
<span id="txtRoom"></span>
```

And am trying to perform a lookup using the Building information. This is what I have so far:

JavaScript:

```
var RoomPriority = 
{ 
"CF.102": "Medium Priority", "E1.1A.360": "High Priority", "E1.1B.338":"Low Priority",
"E1.1B.348":"Low Priority","E1.1B.365":"Low Priority" 
}
var RoomName=txtBuilding.innerHTML+"."+txtFloor.innerHTML+"."+txtRoom.innerHTML
var Room2Search=Roomname
var Urgency=roomlist[Room2Search]
```

And I need to be able to print the urgency level below the listing of the full room information, but I can't get it to work. I've tried div, document write, and inner HTML and nothing is working!

Comment: The way this site works is you really need to show what you tried that isn't working as expected .... then people help you fix **your code** ...not for this to be a free code writing service. See [ask]

Comment: Can you add what's `roomlist`?

Comment: Would you show readers the JS that prints the urgency level? The code here is your HTML and your JS set-up, but not the setting/writing of HTML itself.

Comment: You need a handle to an element in the DOM and you need to set that elements [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).  I see you're *reading* from `txtBuilding`.  If you wanted to change the text in that element, assign to it.  For example: `txtBuilding.innerHTML = "Hello World"`.

Comment: Remember that Javascript is case sensitive. This line should be    var Room2Search = RoomName;